# Alpine - Apk - block upgrade for package that was installed from file

Tags: alpine-linux

## Context

I'm creating a image with
2 packages for which I want to have same version all
the time. I'm installing them from local files.

## How I'm doing it now:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jdk-alpine as build

# PREQUIISTES
RUN apk update

################## SETUP SELENIUM REQUIRMENTS
WORKDIR /tmp_data
COPY --from=build app_build/src/main/resources/docker .

RUN apk add --no-cache ./chromium-122.0.6261.128-r0.apk
RUN apk add --no-cache ./chromium-chromedriver-122.0.6261.128-r0.apk

...
```

## Question

How I can force APK to never upgrade those packages?